# Save multiple jpg files from a url request

Tags: python, url

I have a list of 8 JPG url's that I would like to save locally. At the minute, all I have manged to do is save the last one, while it skips over the rest of the list. Each file would have a different name (F1.jpg, F2.jpg, etc.), but I can't figure out how to do that.
What I currently have is this:

```
for url in lst:
    picture = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "f%s.jpg")
```

I'm assuming there's a simple solution, but I'm fairly new to using python for this type of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
for number, url in enumerate(lst, start=1):
    filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "f{}.jpg".format(number))
```